# Scan barcodes in Android Studio

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am trying to use barcode scanning in android studio.
What you do using the ZXing API is to use your phone camera to recognize a barcode or QR code.
But I have to use the red barcode scanner used by the PDA.
Should I use the relevant library or API?
Which one should I use?

I need to use the red barcode scanner I use on my PDA or the red barcode scanner connected to my phone via USB.

When a barcode is recognized by a PDA or a barcode scanner connected via USB,
Does it have the same effect as Enter after automatically reading the value?
Can I write code after registering the Enter event listener?

Comment: This question is too vague/unclear. ZXing is generally for the built-in camera on a device. If you have a custom device, the manufacturer usually has a barcode SDK which you should be checking. If the barcode scanner device plugs into phone/tablet it could either be custom SDK, custom software keyboard or emulate a hardware keyboard (either can inject text into your app).

Comment: @MorrisonChang Actually most scanner OEMs don't have an SDK.  They generally use a standard like keyboard or SPP.  Generally because scanners are low cost devices that have 20 year old interfaces.  Or at least the ones I've worked with haven't (the exception being Zebra devices).

Comment: @GabeSechan I was thinking Zebra but not sure if they were the only one, also given that OP may have custom hardware (with embedded laser scanner) I'm inclined not to rule out custom SDK (i.e. random POS terminal). Otherwise agree with your assessment, and should correct that text should read "may have SDK" rather than "usually have SDK".

Answer (score 0):

This is unanswerable in the current form.  Physical barcode scanners vary in how they work.  Some of them work by pretending they're a USB (or Bluetooth) keyboard and you can work with them by handling key events.  Some of them use binary protocols- Serial Port Protocol (SPP) is common.  Some of them are configurable-  I know several models that have barcodes you can scan which reconfigure them.

Some keyboard like barcode scanners will send an enter key when data is finished.  Some won't.  Some are configurable.  Read your manual and figure out what your model does.  If you don't have the manual, search online for the model or similar models by the same manufacturer.